# Natural Deduction Proof: {A v B, ¬A v C} ⊢ B v C

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Prove using natural deduction: $(A \lor B), (\lnot A \lor C) ⊢ (B \lor C)$.
My work so far:

```
1     A v B
2     A v C
3      A      :AS
4       ¬A      :AS
5       _|_     :¬E 3,4
6    ¬¬A      :¬I 4-5
7  --
8  ¬A     :AS
```

This is the work that I have come up with, for the past 5 hours. Can you please help me?

Comment: I would try or-elimination on $A \lor B$

Comment: On which line would I try or-elimination for A v B?

Comment: It should be your first step. The way I understand or-eliminiation you do the following:
Assume the left part of the or is true. Now we reach some conclusion. Assume the right part of the or is true. If we now reach the same conclusion, we may use that conclusion below.

Comment: If you want to, I can post an example on how or-elimination works.

Comment: Maybe you should do something with the B and the C

Answer (score -1):

You are setting up for disjunction elimination, so when you derive contradiction, use *explosion* to derive the target conclusion.$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~A\lor B\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Premise}\\~~2.~\lnot A\lor C\hspace{8.5ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~3.~A\hspace{12.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{\fitch{~~4.~\lnot A\hspace{8.5ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{~~5.~\bot\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Negation Elimination}\\~~6.~B\lor C\hspace{5.75ex}\textsf{Explosion (aka }\textit{Ex Falso Quodlibet}\textsf{)}}\\~~\vdots\\~~m.~B\lor C }\\~~\vdots\\~n.~B\lor C}$$

I am sure you can fill out the rest of this "proof by cases".

Answer (score -1):

We have for $(\lnot A \lor C)$:

$1:\text{Premise}; (\lnot A \lor C) : \top$
$2:\text{Assumption}; A : \top$
$3:\text{Negation}(2); \lnot A : \bot$
$4:\text{Insertion}(3\to1); (\bot \lor C) : \top$
$5:\text{Implication}(4); C : \top$

and for $(A \lor B)$

$6:\text{Premise}; (A \lor B) : \top$
$7:\text{Assumption}; A : \bot$
$8:\text{Insertion}(7\to6); (\bot \lor B) : \top$
$9:\text{Implication}(8); B : \top$

and then:

$10:\text{Assumption}; A \lor \lnot A : \top$
$11:\text{Inference}(2,5); (A \supset C) : \top$
$12:\text{Inference}(7,9); (\lnot A \supset B) : \top$
$13:\text{Inference}(10,11,12); (B \lor C) :\top$